# How to get specific element string from element in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, element, nsxmlelement

I have this XML file and I want to fill my list with only **article id and item_description** value.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<articles>
  <article id="i1">
    <item_description>Mobitel Smasung</item_description>
    <single_price>Kom</single_price>
    <unit_of_measure>1250</unit_of_measure>
  </article>
    <article id="i2">
    <item_description>Mobitel DA</item_description>
    <single_price>WD</single_price>
    <unit_of_measure>232</unit_of_measure>
  </article>
</articles>
```

This is what I got so far:

```html
        public void LoadAllArticles()
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(defaultDataPath + @"\saved_articles.xml");

            foreach (var article in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("articles/article"))
            {
                articles = article.Descendants()
                               .Select(element => element.Value)
                               .ToList();

            }
        }
```

How to load only **id + " " + item_description** to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `id` attribute from the parent `article`, move the call to `Descendants()` into the `Select()` lamdba to perform the string concatenation (skip the foreach loop):

```
    articles = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("articles/article")
                   .Select(art => art.Attribute("id").Value + " " + art.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name == "item_description", "<no description>"))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: That way I get "XElement does not contain a definition for Select"

Comment: @SebastianMarjanović Sorry, I left out an important detail, you need to use `Select()` on the whole collection of article elements, answer updated

Comment: Thank you very much, will give it a go! Am new to handling xml files

Comment: Output is i1 <item_description>Mobitel Šmasung</item_description>, is there any other way to remove the tags or should I just string.Replace();

Comment: @SebastianMarjanović `.Value` at the end should give you just the inner text :)